# React Native iOS build failing "unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a web developer and I am building a React Native app for the first time.
The app was working and compiling until I added the FCM support for push notifications.

I followed all the instructions from [React-Native-FCM](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm), using CocoaPods.

Now by build in xCode is failing with this errors:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

My AppDelegate file looks like this:

```
//
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc.
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTBundleURLProvider.h"
#import "RCTRootView.h"
#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Mamaz"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [FIRApp configure];

  #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
  #endif

  return YES;

}

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FCMNotificationReceived object:self userInfo:notification.request.content.userInfo];
    if([[notification.request.content.userInfo valueForKey:@"show_in_foreground"] isEqual:@YES]){
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge | UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
  }else{
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
  }

}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
  [userInfo setValue:@YES forKey:@"opened_from_tray"];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FCMNotificationReceived object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
#else
//You can skip this method if you don't want to use local notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FCMNotificationReceived object:self userInfo:notification.userInfo];
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FCMNotificationReceived object:self userInfo:userInfo];
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}

@end
```

And my PodFile like this:

```
target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem? I cannot even understand what's causing it (since the error message is not very descriptive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a generic error message, you may just get generic answers.

Try:

a) remove `#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299` to get a hint as if your toolchain is correct or not.

b) close Xcode 8.1 (fully close, like with cmd+q), delete the DerivedData folder, empty the trash. And only re-open Xcode after that last step, to correctly re-build the cache.

c) make sure you're using CocoaPods 1.1.1. And in doubt, you can update other tools too. Example: `sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system && sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin`

d) `use_frameworks!` before `target`, as that's how we usually do

e) `pod deintegrate && pod install`, to re-integrate the pods properly

f) lastly, clone your project, and try building from the cloned repo: if it works, delete the old repo and use the new one :). If it still fails, then you can start deleting pieces of code to attempt to get a configuration with a minimal test case that you can share on the CocoaPods issue tracker for investigation.